# How To List Other Academics' Conference Papers Discussing My Artwork?

Tags: publications, conference, cv, fine-performing-arts

I am a Fine Artist, and art historians have discussed my work in conference papers... how would I cite these papers on my CV? Would I include them under "Publications", as I do catalogs, books and art reviews of my work, or should it be under a separate heading? Also, if someone discusses my work in a Master's Thesis, is it appropriate to list that as well?

Comment: Perhaps list them under a heading of "Contributions to published work" with a description of each piece?

Comment: They aren't your publications, which is what people assume(?)to be inside any sections that say 'publications' etc. However, they show the significant external impact of your work and I would list them under a section that is labeled something like that (Evidence of External impact)?. It clearly points out it is other people writing papers, reviews, including your work in their scholarship which I assume is a big deal for someone reading your CV.

Comment: This probably needs input from someone in your field.  In most academic disciplines, a CV should only include works authored by you - it would never include works authored by other people that are *about* you.  Perhaps art is special in this regard, but we would need someone who knows the practices of this field.

Comment: Are you going to use this CV to apply to a university position? Otherwise I am afraid that this question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [some](https://www.collegeart.org/standards-and-guidelines/guidelines/visual-art-cv) [example](https://thepracticalartworld.com/2011/02/12/how-to-write-an-artists-cv-in-10-steps/) [guidelines](https://www.agora-gallery.com/advice/blog/2018/07/16/the-artist-cv/) on fine arts resumes, it seems that one's "publications" or "bibliography" is handled quite differently than in the STEM world, being a collection of things written about you rather than things that you have written.

As such, the particular venue of publication should not matter: a conference article about your work goes in the same general section as an art review.  Now, if you've got a lot of these, you might choose to organize into subsections to make it easier to see the most significant publications, but that's a refinement rather than a high-level guideline.